# How to update Mint-Y theme and icons using a script

Tags: shell-script, linux-mint, upgrade, theme

**Situation:**

> Mint-Y is a work in progress and it will continue to change and to improve, with your feedback, after the Linux Mint 18 release.

Source: https://www.linuxmint.com/rel_sarah_cinnamon_whatsnew.php

**Objective:**
To write a script to automate the update process.

**EDIT1:**
As the releases come steadily in package form, there is obviously no need to use this script. The package names are:

```
mint-y-theme
mint-y-icons
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the username to yours.

```
#!/bin/bash


# https://github.com/linuxmint/mint-y-theme/
# https://github.com/linuxmint/mint-y-icons/


red='\033[1;31m'
green='\033[1;32m'
nocolor='\033[0m'


mkdir -p ~/Downloads/themes-mint/


rm -r -f ~/Downloads/themes-mint/mint-y-theme-master/
rm -r -f ~/Downloads/themes-mint/mint-y-icons-master/


mv ~/Downloads/themes-mint/themes.zip ~/Downloads/themes-mint/themesOLD.zip
mv ~/Downloads/themes-mint/icons.zip ~/Downloads/themes-mint/iconsOLD.zip


wget -q --show-progress -O ~/Downloads/themes-mint/themes.zip https://github.com/linuxmint/mint-y-theme/archive/master.zip
wget -q --show-progress -O ~/Downloads/themes-mint/icons.zip https://github.com/linuxmint/mint-y-icons/archive/master.zip


if ! diff -q ~/Downloads/themes-mint/themes.zip ~/Downloads/themes-mint/themesOLD.zip > /dev/null 2>&1;
then

  unzip -qq -o ~/Downloads/themes-mint/themes.zip -d ~/Downloads/themes-mint/
  cp -r ~/Downloads/themes-mint/mint-y-theme-master/usr/share/themes/* ~/.themes/
  sudo cp -r /home/vlastimil/Downloads/themes-mint/mint-y-theme-master/usr/share/themes/* /usr/share/themes/

  echo -e "Themes ${red}were${nocolor} changed"

else

  echo -e "Themes ${green}not${nocolor} changed"

fi


if ! diff -q ~/Downloads/themes-mint/icons.zip ~/Downloads/themes-mint/iconsOLD.zip > /dev/null 2>&1;
then

  unzip -qq -o ~/Downloads/themes-mint/icons.zip -d ~/Downloads/themes-mint/
  cp -r ~/Downloads/themes-mint/mint-y-icons-master/usr/share/icons/* ~/.icons/
  sudo cp -r /home/vlastimil/Downloads/themes-mint/mint-y-icons-master/usr/share/icons/* /usr/share/icons/

  echo -e "Icons  ${red}were${nocolor} changed"

else

  echo -e "Icons  ${green}not${nocolor} changed"

fi
```